# Proof for $gcd(a^x,b^y)=gcd(a,b)^z$ for a,b,x and y positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, exponentiation, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

I noticed that $\gcd(a^x,b^y)=\gcd(a,b)^z$ for a, b, x, y and z positive integers,

My question is how to prove that?

Additionally assuming the above is correct, when a and b are relatively prime (co-prime):

As $\gcd(a,b)=1$, 
$\gcd(a^x,b^y)=\gcd(a,b)^z=1^z=1$

Does this means that $a^x$ and $b^y$ are co-primes too in this case?

**Update:**

I come to found a counterexample

$\gcd(8^3,4^5)=512$, $\gcd(8,4)=4$ and there is no z positive integer that $4^z=512$

Comment: Try $a=6,b=12,x=2,y=1$.

Comment: What is $z$? The claim is obviously not true if $z$ is free (the LHS is independent of it!)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you write the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$ you might be able to find hypotheses that make your assertion true. Then you can answer your own question here. If you'd rather not do that, consider deleting your question, since you've found your mistake. But do ask more questions when you come across them - just think about them more before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is always true if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ or if $\gcd(a,b)=p$ where $p$ is prime. This is because if $\gcd(a^x,b^y)$ is not a power of $p$ then there is some prime $q\neq p$ which divides $\gcd(a^x,b^y)$ and hence divides $a^x$ and $b^y$. But since $q$ is prime, $q\mid a^x\Longrightarrow q\mid a$, etc., so $q\mid\gcd(a,b)$, which is a contradiction.

For any number $h$ which is neither $1$ nor a prime there are values $a,b$ for which $\gcd(a,b)=h$ but $h<\gcd(a^2,b)<h^2$, giving a counterexample: take $a=h, b=ph$ for some prime $p\mid h$.

Comment: Thank you @Especially Lime, what if one or both a and b are odds? The counterexample seems to occur when both and b are even numbers

Comment: No, e.g. $a=15,b=45$ gives $\gcd(a,b)=15$, $\gcd(a^2,b)=45$. The smallest examples are even, but that's just because $2$ is the smallest prime.

Comment: Especially Lime, you rock! After creating a simple program I found counterexamples with a and b being both odds or one odd and the other even. Ex. $gcd(63,27)=9$ and $gcd(63^5,27^3)=19683$ or  $gcd(63,54)=9$ and $gcd(63^6,54^3)=19683$